# is safe to use drawable.xml as application icon

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

i want to easily update my application icon so i try to use drawables instead of mipmap

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

**my question is it's safe to use that because a draw-able isn't a static image and it -as i understand - maybe change view depended on the parser or maybe icon will be distinct from device to another**

**is what i understand Right ?**

**it's safe ?**

**do you try that before in an application and its work perfectly ?**

thanx advance

Comment: App icon(s) should be located in the mipmap folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's safe.

And i try this in my all application it's work perfectly.

> Don't worry now copyright has been also introduce in new policy.